# Inject a global variable into node context

Tags: node.js

Could i inject a global variable into node context, like "document" in html's script, which any javascript files could access this variable, and it isn't needed to import or require it?

```
//var document = require('document') // i don't need to require it by myself
document.findById('111')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a global in node.js, you assign to the `global` object.

```
// define global
global.myGlobal = 3;

// then use it anywhere
console.log(myGlobal);
```

Here's a good article on module-level variables and globals: [Using global variables in node.js](http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/).

FYI, the node.js module architecture makes it so you do not need to use globals at all.  You can simply `require()` in shared modules in order to share variables.  If you're new to node.js, this may seem a bit odd and a bit inefficient, but you will get used to it and it is the preferred way to develop in node.js because it leads to modularity, testability and robust code.

Here's an interesting article on: [Why global variables are bad](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad).

Comment: What i make likes a js online judge system, previous implement is based on node vm module, but now a new requirement-debugger is coming. So i want to switch to use node.My problem is previous implement inject some global variable in all execute context like document in html, it make it isn't needed to require it explicitly.I want to follow this rule to in my node implement.

Comment: If it's do impossible, maybe i need to change rule, and switch to the way node.js perferred.

Comment: @ChenYang - I showed you how you can make globals if you really want to.  It is not hard - it is possible.  I recommend against using globals for all the reasons in the above referenced article on that topic.

Comment: Sorry,i didn't describe my problem clearly, the global variable i want is auto injected into user(our system users, who write a script)'s  script. User needn't write "global.myGlobal = 3;".

Comment: @ChenYang - Well, I explained how you create global variables in node.js.  You either do it that way or don't use globals.  Your choice.  Letting users write scripts that inject globals into your server's global namespace sounds like a mess to me.

Comment: User give a file path, our system executes command like follow, then myGlobal is accessible in user's js file
node <user's js file path>

Comment: If you're trying to make variables available globally on the client side (in the browser), that's an entirely different issue.  I can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think my system likes a js execute framework more, it installed in user's computer, in this framework some our custom api need to been inject into execute context